# In Typescript, how can I use functions defined in another TS file without puting them in a module?

Tags: function, typescript

I need to use functions defined in a TS file, a file that I'll call "library.ts". I need to use these functions in another file "main.ts". However, for good non-technical reasons (education), I do not want the user to have to know about modules.

For example, I just want them to be able to call ReadText/WriteText without having to worry about a module. X.ReadText is unacceptable.

How can I call a function defined not within a module in library.ts from a function in main.ts?

My VS project says I'm using Typescript 1.1 (TypeScriptToolsVersion)

Comment: "good non-technical reasons" are bad non-technical reasons. Modules are *the* way to structure code. Pretending they don't exist isn't a good way to teach anyone anything, *especially* beginners.

Comment: What if they're 5 years old? Or people with mental issues? Please, I do not want to get into why I cannot use modules, I'm just looking for a technical solution.

Comment: Could you do an import and then merge the module contents into the global namespace then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any code in a file, it doesn't have to be a module.

Here is Library.ts:

```
var globalVariable = 'Hello World';

function globalFunction() {
    alert(globalVariable);
}
```

And here is app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="library.ts" />

globalFunction();
```

Comment: I tried this in a smaller test project and it worked! For some reason , it doesn't in my bigger project. Thanks! I'll post here if I figure out and it's not a simple mistake on my part.

Comment: I reverted my changes, started over and it works now. I dont know why. Thanks!