# How to reuse a method from another external module in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have two modules.

file1.ts

```
  module A {
        export class AA {
        public static methodA {
        // do somenthing
        }
        }
    }
```

file2.ts

```
 module B {
        export class BB {
        public static methodB {
        // do somenthing
        }
        //Here I would like to call the methodA from module A
        }
    }
```

How do I call the method A from the file1.ts in the file2.ts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Typescript, how can I use functions defined in another TS file without puting them in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107015/in-typescript-how-can-i-use-functions-defined-in-another-ts-file-without-puting)

Comment: I put in a module and that it is without module

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid using `module`, use `namespace` instead.

To use other global namespaces you just have to access them by name (As they are global.)

```
namespace A {
  export class AA {
    public static methodA() {
      // do somenthing
    }
  }
}

namespace B {
  export class BB {
    public static methodB() {
      A.AA.methodA();  // <-- like this
    }
  }      
}
```

**Note:** The ordering of the files is important! Anyway, I would recommend moving to ES6 modules.

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20class%20AA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20methodA()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20somenthing%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20class%20BB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20methodB()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20A.AA.methodA()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20like%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I tried, but I got this error  "content-upload.ts:563 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodA' of undefined"